# variable problem: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

This codes gives all time the '"Uncaught TypeError": Cannot read the 'push' property of undefined' error. 
I'm pretty sure the problem is the order within the code. But after many tests I can't get this right.

I have read all of the already placed '"Uncaught TypeError": Cannot read the 'push' property of undefined' posts here on stackoverflow, but none of them solved my problem.

```
var fixedTriangles = [];

function loadClaims(loadingDoneCallback){
    // should be replaced by data from the DB.
    // fixedTriangles = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    // TEST data from db
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // parse the request and put the triangles in de array
    fixedTrianglesStr = request.response;
    // string min last comma
    fixedTriangles = fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
    document.getElementById("dbArray").innerHTML = "dbArray: " + fixedTriangles; 
    //// result = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    console.log("fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles); 
    //// result = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

    // for development only
    showClaimedData();
};
// only lauch callback when data is loaded.
loadingDoneCallback();
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/db.php", true);
request.send();


//// To be clear, I left out the rest of the code. 
//// ...


function onFormSubmit(){
    console.log("close");

    var dataNode = document.getElementById("coordinates");
    var data = dataNode.textContent;
    var dataSplit = data.split("/");
    var fixedTriangles;
    // MAKE IT FIXED
    var returnTriangle = new THREE.Vector3(parseInt(dataSplit[0]),parseInt(dataSplit[1]),parseInt(dataSplit[2]));
    // TEST fixedTriangles: undefined WHY?
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles; 
    //// result = undefined

    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.x)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.y)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.z)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    setAlphaOnTriangle(returnTriangle, 255);

    // save data here.

    showClaimedData();

    var formElement = document.getElementById("form");
    formElement.style.display = "none";
}

//// To be clear, I left out the rest of the code. 
//// ...
```

//// Are the important comments, about the results and errors, to look at.

When the form is sent the value of 'fixedTriangles' has to be sent but instead I get this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' or undefined'.

I have tested already a lot of this possible errors that i have read at other posts with this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' or undefined'.

The rest of this big code works without errors.

Could it be a sequence problem? I have already tested by putting the XMLHttpRequest at the top and bottom?

Done another test and in the console:

this line:

`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles;`

gives:

`fixedTriangles TEST:` 
`2 fixedTriangles TEST: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

So, the first attempt is empty and the next two are giving the result?

Comment: It looks like you never call `loadClaims`

Comment: That i do in the code that i have taken out to be clear. see: //// To be clear, I left out the rest of the code.

Comment: `var fixedTriangles` will set `fixedTriangles` 's value as undefined

Comment: Tested and taken that out, but same error?

Answer (score 3):

In your `onFormSubmit` you override the global `fixedTriangles` by doing `var fixedTriangles;` and when you try to push to it you get the error since it's no longer an array.

Comment: Thanks, but that `var fixedTriangles;` i have put there to test, taken it out doesn't fix it.

Comment: You're also overriding `fixedTriangles` in `loadClaims` via `fixedTriangles  = fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");`.  Also in here: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles; ` you're using `fixedTriangles` as a string but it'd be an array. I'd suggest you to avoid using global variables and then overriding them all over the place.

Comment: `fixedTriangles = fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");` i need to get rid of the last comma and does `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles;` override a variable? It's only there to test.

Comment: `fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");` would return a string, and then you assign that string to your `fixedTriangles` variable, which was supposed to be an array.

Comment: So i have to make it back an array and make it like this? 
 `//// string min last comma
 fixedTrianglesArr = fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
 //// string to array
 fixedTriangles = fixedTrianglesArr.split(","); `

Comment: Just do `fixedTrianglesStr =  fixedTrianglesStr.replace(/,\s*$/, "");` and then use `fixedTrianglesStr` whenever you need a string. For that `request.response` has to be a string as well.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function onFormSubmit(){
    console.log("close");

    var dataNode = document.getElementById("coordinates");
    var data = dataNode.textContent;
    var dataSplit = data.split("/");
    if(!fixedTriangles)
        var fixedTriangles = [];
    // MAKE IT FIXED
    var returnTriangle = new THREE.Vector3(parseInt(dataSplit[0]),parseInt(dataSplit[1]),parseInt(dataSplit[2]));
    // TEST fixedTriangles: undefined WHY?
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles; 
    //// result = undefined

    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.x)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.y)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    fixedTriangles.push(parseInt(returnTriangle.z)); 
    //// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    setAlphaOnTriangle(returnTriangle, 255);

    // save data here.

    showClaimedData();

    var formElement = document.getElementById("form");
    formElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that takes the error out but the array is empty? So, nothing is 'pushed'.

Comment: you're probably overriding the variable somewhere else as well, can you edit the example, or create an external one with the whole code?

Comment: Could it be a sequence problem? I have already tested by putting the XMLHttpRequest at the top and bottom?

Done another test and in the console:

this line:

`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "fixedTriangles TEST: " + fixedTriangles;`

gives:

`fixedTriangles TEST:`  and then `2 fixedTriangles TEST: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

So, the first attempt is empty and the next two are giving the result?

Comment: I will edit the example and check for other `fixedTriangles` overrides first.

Comment: When i put under `setAlphaOnTriangle(returnTriangle, 255);` this `console.log("returnTriangle TEST: " + returnTriangle);` i get this `returnTriangle TEST: [object Object]`. So, empty because we make it empty with: `if(!fixedTriangles)
        var fixedTriangles = [];` Or do i see that wrong?

Comment: no, `if(!fixedTriangles)` check if the variable is undefined or null. and since it returns true it enters the statement defining the variables as an empty array. Whenever fixedTriangles has a value or, more specifically, has a value of an array with some elements, it won't be re-defined as an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Will try your solution on a clean code and test, if not i put an external example up and come back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You define `fixedTriangles` as an array first, but after that define as var so it's overridden.

Comment: Thanks but `var fixedTriangles = [ ];` or `var fixedTriangles;` error stays the same?